# rest template serialize/deserialize Map objects with variosu key , value pairs

Tags: json, jackson, resttemplate

I am using resttemplate with jackson to marshall/unmarshall java/json objects.
What would be the best strategy to  serialize/deserialize

a Map that may contain key value pairs such that keys are strings and values could
be various  types for example an ArrayList of custom objects

I did some research on this site and found the use of @JsonAnyGetter @JsonAnySetter
could be used in this situation, but wasnt sure of how to deserialize in the context
of resttemplate getforobject method. Would one have to write a custom httpmessageconverter
to accomplish the deserialization?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll assume you have a response like this:

```
{ key1: "something", key2: 3}
```

You'll want to have a DTO that has those fields:

```
class CustomResponse {
    private String key1;
    private long key2;
}
```

Make sure you add getters and setters for the above.

Now make your request:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestObject, CustomResponse.class);
```

The request object can be either a DTO like the above or just use Arrays and Maps to construct the requestObject.

You should add this annotation to your response DTOs. This ensures that if there are fields in the response that don't map in your DTO, they will be ignored.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```